# What is the size of GLSL boolean

Tags: c++, opengl, types, glsl

There is a `bool` type for shader variables I'd like to use, but I couldn't find what size it have. This matters because when setting up vertex attribute pointer I specify the type of data which can be

```
GL_BYTE,
GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
GL_SHORT,
GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,
GL_INT,
GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
GL_FLOAT, or
GL_DOUBLE
```

In c++ generally `bool` should have the same size as 4 byte `int`, but can I assume the same for GLSL or does it have only 1 byte?

Comment: I'm pretty sure bool is usually only 1 byte in C++ (at least it's implementation defined), but am prepared to be proved the opposite.

Comment: @ChristianRau Well I searched the web over and you're right, even sizeof returns 1. Can't remember from where I got that..

Comment: The only thing you can say is that it's `sizeof(bool)`. Christian's right, it is implementation-defined and may even depend on compiler settings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> This matters because when setting up vertex attribute pointer I specify the type of data which can be

It's irrelevant, since vertex attributes *cannot* be booleans. From the GLSL 3.30 specification:

> Vertex shader inputs can only be float, floating-point vectors, matrices, signed and unsigned integers and integer vectors.  Vertex shader inputs can also form arrays of these types, but not structures.

Booleans are not on that list.

However, if you want to know what the size of a GLSL `bool` is in terms of [uniform blocks](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object), it has the same size as `uint`: 32-bits.

Comment: so all of those types (except double which is from GL 4.0) are eventually expanded to 4 bytes, and they are relevant only for client-side?

Comment: @Raven: Those are the GLSL types of the vertex shader inputs. What you pass them as attribute values is in many cases up to you; OpenGL has wide latitude for converting data as needed. You don't have to pass 32-bit integers; you can use 8-bit integers if you want. You can pass normalized integer attributes to floating-point inputs. And so forth.